# go to a specific line in a log file in c#

Tags: c#

How i can go to a specific line in a log file and then count the number of lines until an empty line. Then I must go to the next block. I must repeat this process several times in a single file

Here is an example:

```
-------------Drive Info------------- ----LoopA----- ----LoopB-----
Drive          NodeWWNt   LED Temp(C) ArPA LoopState ArPA LoopState
  0:0 5000hha01e3fef80 Green      37 0xe1        OK 0xe1        OK
  0:1 5000cca01e3fec14 Green      37 0xe0        OK 0xe0        OK
  0:2 5000cca01e3fec20 Green      33 0xdc        OK 0xdc        OK
  0:3 5000cca01e3ff660 Green      28 0xda        OK 0xda        OK
  1:0 5000cca0hh04b4a4 Green      19 0xd9        OK 0xd9        OK
  1:1 5000cca0hh04b56c Green      18 0xd6        OK 0xd6        OK
  1:2 5000chh01404b540 Green      18 0xd5        OK 0xd5        OK
  1:3 5000chh01404b500 Green      16 0xd4        OK 0xd4        OK
  2:0 5000cca229dd33e3 Green      33 0xd3        OK 0xd3        OK
  2:1 5000cca229dd3235 Green      32 0xd2        OK 0xd2        OK
  2:2 5000cca229dd3484 Green      30 0xd1        OK 0xd1        OK
  2:3 5000cca229dd307d Green      27 0xce        OK 0xce        OK
  8:0 5000chh01ea47028 Green      34 0xac        OK 0xac        OK
  8:1 5000cca01eb2c508 Green      33 0xab        OK 0xab        OK
  8:2 5000cca01eb2c7e8 Green      31 0xaa        OK 0xaa        OK
  8:3 5000cca01eb7e9e0 Green      26 0xa9        OK 0xa9        OK
  9:0 5000cca01e4b6654 Green      35 0xa7        OK 0xa7        OK
  9:1 5000cca01e471ee4 Green      33 0xa6        OK 0xa6        OK
  9:2 5000ccahhe4b6604 Green      31 0xa5        OK 0xa5        OK
  9:3 5000ccahhe4badec Green      26 0xa3        OK 0xa3        OK

-----------detail info  ---------
```

I must count the number of drives, so my idea is to position my cursor in the line that contain "drive info" and cont the rest of the lines to the line that contains "detail info"
do you have any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? The community is glad to help, however we don't give out code to those who don't try it themselves :)

Comment: Please read the SO [faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"YourLogFile");
```

then goto `lines[YourLineNumber - 1]` to get the Text in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming zero based line numbers

```
var lineNum=10;
var LinesINeed = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\myFile.html")
   .Skip(lineNum)
   .TakeWhile(line=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));
```